# Different ways of Opening a file in C++ on Windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows, file-io

When using `fopen` or `fstream`, it's necessary to specify binary mode in order to prevent character conversions. On UNIX like systems this isn't usually necessary but on Windows it is.

This leads me to wonder if this is still the "natural" way to access filesystem data on this operating system. UNIX has the "everything is a file" architecture going for it, so is there some windows equivalent of a lower level device to access the data? After all, if there are character conversions going on there's the overhead involved in checking each character to see if it needs to be converted. Hopefully opening a file in binary mode would simply disable any such processing but I have my doubts.

Could anybody shed some light on this?

Comment: I just want to say that, while this is a valid question that deserves an answer, your rationale for this approach smells of premature optimization.

Comment: Windows doesn't know anything about character conversions, it is purely a CRT implementation detail.

Comment: Nate, you're probably right. I don't intend to actually do anything about this "issue" since it probably isn't an issue. But I'd like to know what's going on under the hood.

Comment: I wish people would stop banging on about premature optimization.  it's getting old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the C run-time libraries does what the C run-time libraries does.

Windows actually has *most* things as a file (or should I say objects) a file name in Windows is actually an object in the global namespace `\??\`. If you look up the documentation for `CreateFile` on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) there's a lot more to it, especially if you go digging through the [Windows kernel documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff566424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you're curious about objects on Windows, you can also download and run `WinObj` from [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657).

Depending on what type of project your working on, I'd put an abstraction layer around IO just to be able to fully utilize what's in Windows but not in the C run-time libraries. I rarely write code for different platforms not going through the native API on each platform (or through some intermediary abstraction).

Comment: not to nitpick, but what do you mean by your last sentence? Also what sorts of things would be "in Windows but not in the C runtime libraries"?

Comment: Sounds like he wants to be able to take advantage of the filesystem features that the OS gives you, rather than relying on the standard C library which gives you somewhat of a lowest common denominator approach.

Comment: @Steven Lu, yes, Nate C-K is right, there are a lot of things in Windows APIs that aren't not exposed through the C run-time libraries. e.g asynchronous IO and the ability to memory map and lock regions of a file. For everyday use this is not necessary but it's powerful stuff that exists in most operating system but not in the C run-time libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use windows file handles. [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [ReadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365747%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

This is pretty similar to the Unix way of doing things.  Lots of things can be done using these functions.  Not sockets mind but its about as close as you'll get!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there are Win32-specific functions.  Purists will say it makes your code non-portable.  And it does!  But who cares, you're writing a Windows program.

[OpenFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365430%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), [etc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364232%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: And if you do care, you can write a simple wrapper function which checks if the Windows API is available at compile-time.

Comment: The folks running Linux or Mac OS care! :-)